# Python break from if statement to else

Tags: python, if-statement, break

(I'm a Python newbie, so apologies for this basic question, I for some reason couldn't find an answer to.)

I have a nested `if` statement with the `if` statement of an `if`/`else` block. In the *nested* `if` statement, if it it meets the criteria, I'd like the code to break to the `else` statement. When I put a `break` in the nested `if`, though, I'm not sure if it's breaking to the `else` statement.

I'd like to find the longest substring in alphabetical order of a given string, `s`. Here's my code:

```
s = 'lugabcdeczsswabcdefghij'
longest = 1
alpha_count = 1
longest_temp = 1
longest_end = 1
for i in range(len(s)-1):
    if (s[i] <= s[i+1]):
        alpha_count += 1
        if (i+1 == (len(s)-1)):
            break
    else:
        longest_check = alpha_count
        if longest_check > longest:
            longest = longest_check
            longest_end = i+1
        alpha_count = 1
print(longest)
print('Longest substring in alphabetical order is: ' + 
    s[(longest_end-longest):longest_end])
```

(Yes, I realize there's surely lots of unnecessary code here. Still learning!)

At this nested `if`:

```
if (i+1 == (len(s)-1)):
            break
```

...if `True`, I'd like the code to break to the `else` statement. It doesn't seem to break to that section, though. Any help?

Comment: break is used in loop statements.  I think you want to use flags.

Comment: The `break` statement is only use to break from while and for loops: see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#break What are you wanting ? A way to go to the else block if you encounter your current break ?

Comment: @XavierC.Yes, that's exactly what I want. If I encounter the current break, I'd like to go to the else block I have written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`break` is used when you want to break out of loops not if statments. You can have another `if` statement that executes this logic for you like this:

```
if (s[i] <= s[i+1]):
    alpha_count += 1
elif (i+1 == (len(s)-1)) or (add boolean expression for else part in here too something like s[i] > s[i+1]):
    longest_check = alpha_count
    if longest_check > longest:
        longest = longest_check
        longest_end = i+1
    alpha_count = 1
```

What this snippet is doing is evaluating two booleans, both are for the `else` part. However, it says either execute in case of `else` from first `if` or in case of `(i+1 == (len(s)-1))`

Comment: I believe the first if statement should have an and boolean as well:
if (s[i] <= s[i+1]) and (i+1 < (len(s)-1)):
        alpha_count += 1
    elif (s[i] <= s[i+1]) and (i+1 == (len(s)-1)):

Comment: if you want the first one to execute whenever `i + 1 < (len(s) - 1)`